# Read Browser Session Periodically

Tags: php

I want to clean some session variables after every 15 minutes through a php script. PHP script is working fine when rum from a web browser. I need the process to be automated. Please suggest the solution for it.

Comment: Are your sessions stored in database? Do you want to clear these keys for every session? Or just some sessions? (All sessions would be all current users for instance)

Comment: How do you run a PHP script from a "web browser" ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a certain script to be run **every 15 minutes**, then create a `cronjob`, that executes your script every 15 minutes.

Here is a small tutorial how to do it: http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml